# Strange symfony2 issue when updating vendors with composer

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm experiencing a rather strange problem with a Symfony site I'm working on. For some reason, when I write `composer update` or `composer install` I get the following result:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file



  [Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]
  Cannot import resource "Z:\path\to\project\app/config\config.yml" from "Z:\path\to\project\app/config/config_dev.yml". (There is no ext
  ension able to load the configuration for "imports" (in Z:\path\to\project\app/config\config.yml). Loo
  ked for namespace "imports", found "framework", "security", "twig", "mon
  olog", "swiftmailer", "assetic", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra", "com
  mon_common", "common_security", "dashboard", "receipts", "hr",
  "service", "users", "partners", "storage", "web_profiler",
  "sensio_distribution")






  [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
  There is no extension able to load the configuration for "imports" (in Z:\path\to\project\app/config\config.yml). Looked for namespace "imports", found "framework", "security
  ", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "assetic", "doctrine", "sensio_framewo
  rk_extra", "common_common", "common_security", "dashboard", "receip
  ts", "hr", "service", "users", "partners", "storage", "
  web_profiler", "sensio_distribution"



Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception



  [RuntimeException]
  An error occurred when executing the ""cache:clear --no-warmup"" command.
```

config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    globals:
        sitename: "%sitename%"
        session: {}

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"

    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ CommonSecurityBundle ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java

    assets:
        base_css:
            inputs:
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/public/css/admin.css'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/public/css/superfish/superfish.css'

        timer_js:
            inputs:
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/public/js/time.js'

    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        # path:     "%database_path%"
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true


# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

config_dev.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

framework:
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml"
        strict_requirements: true
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }

web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:   stream
            path:   "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level:  debug
        console:
            type:   console
            bubble: false
        # uncomment to get logging in your browser
        # you may have to allow bigger header sizes in your Web server configuration
        #firephp:
        #    type:   firephp
        #    level:  info
        #chromephp:
        #    type:   chromephp
        #    level:  info

assetic:
    use_controller: true

#swiftmailer:
#    delivery_address: me@example.com
```

parameters.yml

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_pgsql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 5432
    database_name: db_name
    database_user: db_user
    database_password: db_pass
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: en
    secret: asdBHwmI1hsjKjanJK2WD@wdnak
```

security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_STORAGE_WRITE: ROLE_STORAGE_READ
        ROLE_ADMIN:         ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN:   [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        main_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [ in_memory ]

        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                    admin: { password: password, roles: [ 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN' ] }


    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login:
            pattern:  ^/login$
            security: false

        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            logout:     true
            anonymous:  false
            logout:
                path:   logout
                target: /
                invalidate_session: false
            simple_form:
                authenticator: authentication_token
                check_path:    login_check
                login_path:    login

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/,      roles: ROLE_USER }
```

I've got no idea why it says it can't `import` the files in the `imports` section - they exist and are writable/readable. Can someone shed a light on what's happening here?

Symfony version: 2.4.2
Composer version: 70a20ebcc19f1ea8ab0954a4fbdce208b30085e7 2014-03-12 16:07:58

Comment: Could you show the config file?

Comment: and `config_dev.yml `?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that one. Question updated again.

Comment: try manually removing the cache and vendor folders, from within the project folder `rm -rf vendor/` & `rm -rf app/cache/*` then try again. It is also possible this is a permission issue. have a look at: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#book-installation-permissions

Comment: I've tried that already, but unfortunately that doesn't work. Also, it's not a permission issue - it's running on a windows machine and I've got r/w permission to the folders.

Comment: What version of symfony are you using? This can be found in your composer.json. And what are you using for you webserver? WAMPSERVER?

Comment: The symfony version is 2.4. The web server isn't that important - the product is working fine after you install the proper vendors. The problem is with the `composer install/update` and the exception above. I can't seem to figure out why is this failing...

Comment: Are you using the latest composer version? `composer self-update`

Comment: Yes, I'm using the latest version of composer `Composer version 70a20ebcc19f1ea8ab0954a4fbdce208b30085e7 2014-03-12 16:07:58`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50085/discussion-between-chausser-and-tftd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some times crazy things happen to files where extra bytes get inserted at the start of the file. You can try recreating the file with the contents by hand. Copy pasting my include those bytes.